# Checking for permissions using Romanbican/roles in Laravel 5.1 doesn´t work

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, laravel-blade, roles

I'm doing a proyect where I control views, controllers, etc using the Romanbican/roles package.

I have set all the configuration required for the role package working, I have set that every user will have just one role, and I also have created a admin area where I can attach or detach permission to a specific role.

The Super Admin Role doesn't have the permission the permission number 83 that is the one to control the access to Compras menu. So, every user that had the role of Super admin wouldn't see the Compras link in the nav bar.

[nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DmbH.jpg)

The thing, is that everything works fine when the project is on local deployment, but when I put it on Production, some permissions validation doesn't work.

and It is still showing the link to Compras

[nav bar (production)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlBRA.jpg)

This is how I have done the permission validation in the nav bar section:

```
@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->can('menu.compras'))
<li class="dropdown ">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Compras<span
                class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="grid-demo">
            <div class="yamm-content">
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <ul class="col-sm-6">
                        <li class="dropdown-header"><h4>Categorias</h4></li>
                        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->can('menu.categorias'))
                            <li><a href="{!!URL::to('Categoria')!!}">Listado de Categorías</a>
                            </li>
                        @else
                            <li>------------</li>
                        @endif
                        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->can('crear.categoria'))
                            <li><a href="{!!URL::to('Categoria/create')!!}">Agregar
                                    categoría</a>
                            </li>
                        @else
                            <li>------------</li>
                        @endif
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header"><h4>Bodegas</h4></li>
                        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->can('menu.bodegas'))
                            <li><a href="{!!URL::to('Bodega')!!}">Listado de Bodegas</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li>------------</li>
                        @endif
                        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->can('crear.bodega'))
                            <li><a href="{!!URL::to('Bodega/create')!!}">Agregar Bodega</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li>------------</li>
                        @endif
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header"><h4>Proveedores</h4></li>
                        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->can('menu.proveedores'))
                            <li><a href="{!!URL::to('Proveedor')!!}">Listado de Proveedores</a>
                            </li>
                        @else
                            <li>------------</li>
                        @endif
                        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->can('crear.proveedor'))
                            <li><a href="{!!URL::to('Proveedor/create')!!}">Agregar
                                    Proveedor</a>
                            </li>
                        @else
                            <li>------------</li>
                        @endif
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header"><h4>Productos</h4></li>
                        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->can('menu.productos'))
                            <li><a href="{!!URL::to('Producto')!!}">Listado de Productos</a>
                            </li>
                        @else
                            <li>------------</li>
                        @endif
                        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->can('crear.producto'))
                            <li><a href="{!!URL::to('Producto/create')!!}">Agregar Producto</a>
                            </li>
                        @else
                            <li>------------</li>
                        @endif
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="col-sm-6">
                        <li class="dropdown-header"><h4>Cotizaciones</h4></li>
                        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->can('menu.cotizaciones'))
                            <li><a href="{!!URL::to('Cotizacion')!!}">Listado de
                                    Cotizaciones</a>
                            </li>
                        @else
                            <li>------------</li>
                        @endif
                        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->can('crear.cotizacion'))
                            <li>
                                <a href="" data-toggle="modal"
                                   data-target="#CotizacionBodegaModal">
                                    Crear cotizacion
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        @else
                            <li>------------</li>
                        @endif
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header"><h4>Entradas</h4></li>
                        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->can('menu.entradas'))
                            <li><a href="{!!URL::to('Entrada')!!}">Listado de Entradas</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li>------------</li>
                        @endif
                        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->can('crear.entrada'))
                            <li><a href="{!!URL::to('Entrada/create')!!}">Hacer Entrada</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li>------------</li>
                        @endif
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
@endif
```

And I have also tried with te Bican package blade extension :

```
@permission('menu.compras') //menu.compras is the premission slug 
.
.
.
@endpermission
```

But it also doesn't work.

And what I couldn´t find is why some permission validations do work and others do not.

For example: the Role list menu validation it's working:

In this case the super admin users couldn't see the link to the role list and instead it will show "-------"

Could somebody help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Pd: I couldn't submit more images to show because I'm new at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out by myself that I was missing the Permissions Inheriting concept, that basically is that user with a role with higher level is inheriting permission from roles with lower level.

So as some users had higher level than others, that's why those users could access to those links without the required permission.

This is the link to the package documentacion with all the explanation about Permissions Inheriting

[Permissions Inheriting](https://github.com/romanbican/roles#permissions-inheriting)